# Where are Django registration redux defaut files stored

Tags: django, django-registration

After I pip installed django-registration-redux, I want to modify its defaul froms.py, registration/registration/, but can not find that directory. And can not find the default files in any directory. Anyone know how to access those files thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the file location of a python module (it could be pip installed) using `.__file__`. E.g.

```
>>> import registration
>>> registration.__file__
'/some/path/to/site-packages/registration/__init__.py'
```

This should help you locate where the module is physically located on your machine.

Pip installed package files are downloaded into the `site-packages` directory of your Python installation or virtualenv. You can use python itself to locate the directory:

```
python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"
```

With that being said, you should avoid modifying files in `site-packages`. Any changes you make are likely not tracked in version control. Consider either forking the project and installing directly from git, or download the source and add it to your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the `site-packages` folder of your python installation. Hopefully you're using `virualenv` and then your in use python is in the **lib** folder from the virtualenv folder of your app.

Probably is not a good thing to modify the package itself. You can subclass any of the default forms or views in your project code and add fields, modify validation, etc.

Comment: thanks, but I have tried site-packages folder, but its not there, but i can tell that its installed cuz the registration is working properly

Comment: are you using virtualenv?

Comment: So you have a `venv` folder inside your projec folder?

Comment: my project is in virtualenv/src and I was looking into virtualenv/Lib/site packages but couldn't see it. I tried pip install in both Src folder and virtualenv folder.

Comment: It's activated your virtual environment when you're using `pip install`?

Comment: try running this: `python -c "import registration; print(registration.__file__)"` - it'll give you the file location of the registration module

Comment: @DerekKwok thanks I found the files, but it's in appdata/local... folder. I double checked, when I did pip install, I was in my virtual environment directory and it is activated, should I manually move files from local to virtualenv folder? Or how can I properly install it in virtualenv directory?

Comment: ah never mind, used virtualenv --no-site-packages and it worked, thanks a lot! Appreciate all your helps!